# Impossible to build android project if it is located in "bin" directory

Tags: android, ant, android-build

My android project is located in directory **D:\testandroid\bin\app1**.
I cannot build it because android build procedure sets wrong jars path.

```
D:\testandroid\bin\app1> and debug
...
-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: D:\testandroid\ant-build\app1\libs\CordovaLib.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to D:\testandroid\bin\app1\bin\classes
    [javac] D:\testandroid\bin\app1\src\com\phonegap\testapp\TestApp.java:23: package org.apache.cordova does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.*;
```

As you can see it sets jars path to **D:\testandroid\ant-build\app1\libs\CordovaLib.jar**, but correct jars path should be **D:\testandroid\bin\app1\libs\CordovaLib.jar**
It replaces **bin** directory with **ant-build** directory by some reason.

How to fix this problem?
Unfortunately I cannot move android project from bin directory.